# Nagios suddenly stops working

Tags: server, nagios3

I have configure passive checks on one my host system

for this i am using nsca.

it was running fine.

suddenly host is showing down on the monitoring. but host was fine and running

when i check the logs on the host
showing

[1347941895] Warning: Attempting to execute the command "/submit_check_result host.example.com 'Current Load' OK 'OK - load average: 0.69, 0.53, 0.42'" resulted in a return code of 127.  Make sure the script or binary you are trying to execute actually exists...

i restarted nagios services many times but still it is showing the same error.

can anyone help me regarding this.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

i found it was the configuration of nagios.cfg file eventhandlers were not enabled.